# How can I force focus or fix a blurry and 'washed out' Apple Thunderbolt Display camera?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, camera, thunderbolt-display

The built-in camera of my Apply Thunderbolt Display (MC914LL/B 27") is always blurry. Items up close look better, but are still blurry. In fact, everything looks bright and washed out like a bad Instagram filter, like the beach after waking up from a sandy nap, or after walking out of the eye doctor with those dilating eye drops...

It is blurry for all apps.
It is blurry with my MacBook Pro lid open or closed.
It is blurry before and after plugging in my Thunderbolt cable.
The screen and camera lens are clean.

The built-in camera on my MacBook Pro, connected to this Thunderbolt Display, is crystal clear.

I have the latest display firmware, 1.2, and the latest MacBook Pro updates.

Any ideas on how to fix this / force it to focus on a specific distance?

Best,
Adam

Screenshots:

[image: Microsoft Lync]

[image: FaceTime]

[image: FaceTime - up-close / Macro mode]

Comment: did you take the protective sticker off ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Good question! Yes :)

Comment: Are you using Skype, if yes go to preferences and select Thunderbolt camera to test.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have tried it with the same results in both FaceTime and Microsoft Lync. The built-in Macbook Pro camera works perfectly. I believe the issue is with the focus distance of the built-in Thunderbolt Display camera. I attached some screenshots.

Comment: thanks for the screen shots! again make sure there is no almost invisible sticker on the lens. Next, check the Thunderbolt cable. Try changing the Thunderbolt resolution.

Comment: also you could try this app (free to try) http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/

Comment: @Buscar웃 I did try iGlasses... that didn't help. :( The zoom did not adjust the focus - neither did any of the other functions. I confirmed there is no sticker, and tried changing the Thunderbolt resolution... no fix. Next step - another Thunderbolt cable!

Comment: you keep coming up with stuff you tried, it would help if you list those in your question, or did I miss it.

Comment: This definitely looks like the lenses aren't setup correctly, especially because it can focus up close. I would contact Apple for a repair/replacement. It seems like either there are moving lenses that aren't moving, or a lens element is missing entirely—but I don't know what kind of lenses are in a Thunderbolt display's camera. I don't think it's a software issue or anything you can fix yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed mine, my camera is inside the TB Display, I took the camera out and since it is fixed focus I turned the objective lens  1 quart and connected again. It was fixed!

Instructions to tear down the monitor are at  Ifixit 
https://es.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+Thunderbolt+Display+Teardown/6525

[image]